# Can cotire be made to work properly with Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, precompiled-headers

**PROBLEM SUMMARY**
We took a crack at using **cotire**, the Compile-Time Reducer, as our precompiled header system due to the extremely long compile times caused by usage of the Boost C++ template library.  We are getting poor to dangerous results-- the precompiled headers seem to be constantly rebuilt, and are occasionally masking build problems.  Specifically, back-to-back builds result in differing hashes of the actual cotire precompiled headers themselves, and, when attempting incremental builds, the precompiled headers are rebuilt every time, even when no header material has changed.

**BACKGROUND**
The project is a Linux CMake build using g++ 6.3.1, which produces, as its artifacts, an installable shared-library and several executables.  Possibly of note, we have no interest in using unity builds, due to constant requirements for rapid-iteration development.  However, the project is very large, hence the interest in cotire.

It is worth noting that, to avoid unexpected interactions while troubleshooting this issue, we have disabled **ccache**, the compiler cache.  (Our intent is to eventually enable ccache if and only if we get consistent, expected results from cotire, or after we give up and remove cotire.)

The project uses C++03 (though building with 11 did not change our results for purposes of this question) and relies extensively on the Boost C++ library.  Specifically, we make constant use of Boost Signal-Slot, boost::bind, boost::function, and quite a few of the iteration capabilities.  Boost implements all of these via extensive template meta-programming and variant self-inclusion.

It is possible, though not entirely straightforward, to "blacklist" header files from cotire, excluding them from the generated precompiled headers.  We attempted to blacklist various subdirectories within Boost itself (Boost includes some 900 different header files, so we mostly restricted ourselves to its immediate subdirectories).  This seemed to produce improved results-- blacklisting certain parts of Boost resulted in back-to-back clean builds that produced matching precompiled header hashes.

Unfortunately, after a more significant delay-- perhaps ten minutes-- a third attempt to do a clean build resulted in a different hash for the precompiled header.

At this point, our working theory was that various special preprocessor symbols such as __TIME__ and __DATE__ were somehow getting mangled into cotire's input.  Searching for these in Boost's headers does indeed produce a number of hits in wave, spirit, etc.  Presumably this causes cotire to believe that the headers have changed in some way, because it attempts to rebuild the entire precompiled header with every build (though not with every compilation unit; we tentatively believe we have it integrated into the build process correctly).

**QUESTION**
Has anyone successfully used cotire with gcc/g++ and Boost?  Were any unusual steps required, as opposed to using cotire in a project without Boost?

We are interested in cotire *specifically*; results from, for example, Visual Studio's precompiled header system might be interesting but are unlikely to be helpful.  However, if you are troubleshooting similar issues and wish to provide your observations here, please feel free to do so.

Comment: I had no trouble doing so, although I had boost in `/usr/local/include`. Assuming you don't, there shouldn't be a problem; just point cotire at *your* project (don't build boost with cotire)

Comment: Since you prefer to retain  your project layout having many translation units, have you considered using `icecc` aka IceCream?  It lets you farm out compilation of individual translation units to separate machines on a LAN.  I've used it before with Boost in projects that had long compile times, and it gave huge speedups (assuming you have say a dozen decent machines on your LAN).  https://github.com/icecc/icecream

Comment: Well, if we go down that road, we'll probably just make a build server with some serious hardware, but we have reasons for needing the individual workstations to chew through builds on their own in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a minimal reference project that will demonstrate the problem; I'll try to get some time to do so.